# Regular expression to replace HTML content

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace HTML content with regular expression.

from

```
<A HREF="ZZZ">test test ZZZ<SPAN>ZZZ test test</SPAN></A>
```

to

```
<A HREF="ZZZ">test test AAA<SPAN>AAA test test</SPAN></A>
```

note that only words outside HTML tags are replaced from ZZZ to AAA.

Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: please read the first answer to this question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks Mat for the referral. After reading the link, I've simplified the question, since I know the HTML will be "regular" type of HTML.

Comment: Then you misread that link. Don't use regex to parse HTML, it's too complex. Use an (X)HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a well-formed html document with outer/enclosing tags like `<html>`, I would think the easiest way would be to look for the `>` and `<` signs:

```
/(\>[^\>\<]*)ZZZ([^\>\<]*\<)/$1AAA$2/
```

If you're dealing with HTML fragments that may not have enclosing tags, it gets a little more complicated, you'd have to allow for start of string and end of string

Example JS (sorry, missed the tag):

```
alert('<A HREF="ZZZ">test test ZZZ<SPAN>ZZZ test test</SPAN></A>'.replace(/(\>[^\>\<]*)ZZZ([^\>\<]*\<)/g, "$1AAA$2"));
```

**Explanation**: for each match that

- starts with `>`: `\>`
- follows with any number of characters that are neither `>` nor `<`: `[^\>\<]*`
- then has "ZZZ"
- follows with any number of characters that are neither `>` nor `<`: `[^\>\<]*`
- and ends with `<`: `\<`

Replace with

- everything before the ZZZ, marked with the first capture group (parentheses): `$1`
- AAA
- everything after the ZZZ, marked with the second capture group (parentheses): `$2`

Using the "g" (global) option to ensure that all possible matches are replaced.

Comment: Thanks TAO, you're great.. if you have brief explanation about the regex it will be helpful, thanks again...

Comment: done, hope that helps. I would recommend you use a DOM-traversal method if possible through, as outlined in @Suor's answer and @Tim Down's comment; this type of solution will always be more reliable. As @Jens noted, the regexp solution in this answer will probably break under some circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

You could walk all nodes, replacing text in text ones (.nodeType == 3):

Something like:

```
element.find('*:contains(ZZZ)').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType === 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/ZZZ/g,'AAA')
})
```

Or same without jQuery:

```
function replaceText(element, from, to) {
    for (var child = element.firstChild; child !== null; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3)
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(from,to)
        else if (child.nodeType === 1)
            replaceText(child, from, to);
    }
}

replaceText(element, /ZZZ/g, 'AAA');
```

Comment: `textContent` isn't universally supported for text nodes. Use either `nodeValue` or `data` properties instead. Also, if the first parameter passed to a string's `replace()` method is a string, only the first occurrence of that string will be replaced. Use a regular expression with the global flag (e.g. `/ZZZ/g`) instead to replace all occurrences.

Comment: Hi Suor, your JS function is answering the question i described. But i just realized that I oversimplify actual issue. I need to change from ZZZ to something like <span class="highlight>AAA</span>, and above function -- will render <span> tag as "Text" instead of HTML

Comment: Then you should create that span node and insert it there. You can do `var html = this.nodeValue.replace(from, to); $(this).replaceWith(html)` instead of simple nodeValue assignment. And it would be trickier but possible without jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The best idea in this case is most certainly to not use regular expressions to do this. At least not on their own. JavaScript surely has a HTML Parser somewhere?

If you really must use regular expressions, you could try to look for every instance of ZZZ that is followed by a "<" before any ">". That would look like

```
ZZZ(?=[^>]*<)
```

This might break horribly if the code contains HTML comments or script blocks, or is not well formed.

Comment: yep, that makes sense - HTMLcomments, script blocks, or any other xhtml CDATA would mess things up no matter what regexp you come up with

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = '<DIV>ZZZ test test</DIV><A HREF="ZZZ">test test ZZZ</A>';
var rpl = str.match(/href=\"(\w*)\"/i)[1];
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp(rpl + "(?=[^>]*<)", "gi"), "XXX"));
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

replace:

```
>([^<>]*)(ZZZ)([^<>]*)<
```

with:

```
>$1AAA$3<
```

but beware all the savvy suggestions in the post linked in the first comment to your question!

Comment: beware!? i did not mean it, sorry... take into account all the savvy suggestions....

Comment: hi sergio, thank you for your suggestion, i like your idea.. it almost works, but not perfect yet , it gave me -- < A HREF="ZZZ"/>test test AAA</S P A N>ZZZ test test</SPAN >< /A >

Comment: try this link: http://regexr.com?2tpq1, it is flash-based regex engine initialized with my suggestion... it seems to work ok... are you using the "g" flag (for global replace)?